# Cannot find directory in context of main.cpp (Allegro with CMake)

Tags: c++, cmake, allegro5

I'm trying to create a library that links against allegro5 media library using CMake. And then, I want to use my library in an executable.

My directory structure is:

```
src
 |----core
        |------src
        |------tests
        |------CMakeLists.txt
 |----main.cpp
 |----CMakeLists.txt
```

The CMakeLists.txt file inside the core folder is:

```
set(MY_HEADERS #My header files here)
set(MY_SRC #My source files here)

add_library(MyLib ${MY_HEADERS} ${MY_SRC})
target_include_directories(MyLib PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")

## Allegro Lib

set(ALLEGRO_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/packages/allegro5/include")

if(WIN32)
    file(GLOB ALLEGRO_LIB "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/packages/allegro5/windows/x86/lib/*.lib")
    add_library(Allegro SHARED IMPORTED)
    set_target_properties(Allegro PROPERTIES
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${ALLEGRO_DIR}
        IMPORTED_IMPLIB ${ALLEGRO_LIB}
    )
    target_link_libraries(MyLib PRIVATE Allegro)
    file(GLOB ALLEGRO_DLL "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/packages/allegro5/windows/x86/bin/*.dll")
    foreach(dll ${ALLEGRO_DLL})
        add_custom_command(TARGET MyLib POST_BUILD
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
            ${dll} $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyLib>)
    endforeach()
endif()
```

Now in my, top level CMakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(MyProject)
enable_testing()

add_subdirectory(core)
add_executable(MyGame main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MyGame MyLib)
```

In my IDE (Visual Studio) I see that the include statement for "allegro5/allegro.h" in my source files is inside core folder is giving me the warning "Cannot find directory allegro5 in search paths ... in context of ../src/main.cpp".

When I build the project I get the errors:

```
Cannot open source file 'allegro5/allegro'
Cannot open include file 'allegro5/allegro.h': No such file or directory.
```

This error only happens if I reference `MyLib` in main.cpp. (My main does not have any code, just a hello world statement):

```
// #include "MyLib.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    /*const auto engine = &MyLib::EngineManager::getInstance();
    engine->start();
    const auto display = &MyLib::DisplayManager::getInstance();

    auto displayConfig = DisplayConfig();
    displayConfig.fullscreen = false;
    const auto displayId = display->createDisplay(displayConfig);*/
}
```

I guess this has something to do with the visibility I'm setting somewhere? I can't quite figure out how to fix. Appreciate your help, thanks!

EDIT:

When `PRIVATE` to `PUBLIC`, I get the following linker error:

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_al_install_system referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl mylib::EngineManager::start(void)" (?start@EngineManager@mylib@@SAXXZ)   C:\Users\xxx\src\out\build\x64-Debug\src    C:\Users\xxx\src\out\build\x64-Debug\main.cpp.obj
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The include directory for `allegro5` is defined as `ALLEGRO_DIR` in your CMake:

```
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/packages/allegro5/include
```

Therefore, with the `#include "allegro5/allegro.h"`, the full path to the header file would be appended:

```
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/packages/allegro5/include/allegro5/allegro.h
```

Be sure this path is correct and the file exists.

In addition, you set the `INTERFACE` include directories on the imported `Allegro` target, but you link it to `MyLib` using the `PRIVATE` keyword. This means the usage requirements of `Allegro` are **not** propagated to the `MyGame`. You should use `PUBLIC` for this link step instead if you want the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` of `Allegro` to also be transitively propagated to `MyGame`:

```
    target_link_libraries(MyLib PUBLIC Allegro)
```

CMake has a good [example](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#transitive-usage-requirements) demonstrating this in their documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I changed to `PUBLIC` when I link to Allegro. Then I get the error "Unresolved external symbol" when linking to Allegro from MyLib.

Comment: @swdon Did `MyLib` build successfully when using `PRIVATE`? As far as I know, switching from `PRIVATE` to `PUBLIC` should not change the link interface between `MyLib` and `Allegro`. Feel free to add the *specific* error to your question post.

Comment: Sorry, mistake. The linker error is in the `MyGame` project. It fails to link to Allegro5. I will post the exact error but I think there's a lot of other questions regarding linker errors, so I will check them first before wasting your time :)

Comment: @swdon If `MyGame` doesn't link to Allegro5, you probably also have to set [`INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES.html#prop_tgt:INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES) to `${ALLEGRO_LIB}` in your call to `set_target_properties()`.

Comment: I tried making this change but the same error remains. I posted the exact error as an edit.

Comment: @swdon There are also some forums online mentioning the architecture of Allegro. Be sure if Allegro libraries are 32-bit, that your CMake builds a `Win32` Visual Studio solution, not an `x64` one.

Comment: I was building for x64 all this time... Thanks so much!